# iOS Speech Recognition repeatedly pauses and resumes its transcription

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

I'm facing a weird behavior on iOS speech recognition by the Speech framework.
It pauses its transcription for a while and resumes it after a while without doing anything from the app side (literally I just keep waiting holding my iPhone and it resumes suddenly).
Also, it does not always happen but sometimes does.

I use on-device mode by setting `requiresOnDeviceRecognition` to true so, from my understanding, there shouldn't be a one-minute limitation as there is in network mode.

I have observed two things as of now.

First, I looked into the Energy Report in Xcode, and it shows some clues. It seems to stop completely its activity while it pauses transcription.

*When it's working:*
[image]

*When it pauses:*
[image]
*When it resumes:*
[image]
Secondly, there are the Xcode console logs below when it resumes the transcription. Not sure if it's related to the issue but just FYI.

```
2023-07-25 17:54:25.249013+0900 ***[2968:837713] [tcp] tcp_input [C87.1.1.1:3] flags=[R] seq=3535393450, ack=0, win=0 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=3535393450, snd_una=907886974
2023-07-25 17:54:25.251148+0900 ***[2968:837713] [tcp] tcp_input [C87.1.1.1:3] flags=[R] seq=3535393450, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=3535393450, snd_una=907886974
```

Is this a kind of Speech framework requirement? I'm happy to share the implementation if it's necessary. Thanks.

---

###### [Update]

Another observation is, while it's NOT working, some threads seem to be busy. There appears to be a pattern of inactivity for approximately 40-50 seconds.
[image]

Interestingly, this busy period does not appear when I keep speaking while the transcription is working. Then after I stop speaking, the inactivity pattern starts again.

[image]

---

###### [Update 2]

Even while the transcription is NOT working, `tapBlock` installed to the inputNode of AVAudioEngine keeps being called back. `self.recognitionRequest` is also not nil.

```
let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
    self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
}
```

Comment: maybe the hardware has been used by another app like siri , try to swap down the top menu while monitoring your app profile and see if there is another app is using same hardware , you can see it as a green dot on both apps or only your app

Comment: @Kodr.F Thanks! I couldn't understand well the latter part. Could you elaborate on it? (You can probably post it as an answer not comment here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the cause and solution.

I was using the `.voiceChat` mode for AVAudioSession. But after I replaced it with the `.default`, the issue stops appearing!

According to the [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/mode/1616455-voicechat), it says it somehow optimizes a device's I/O in `.voiceChat` mode, so it might not be compatible with SpeechRecognizer I guess.

> Use this mode for Voice over IP (VoIP) apps that use the playAndRecord category. When you set this mode, the session optimizes the device’s tonal equalization for voice and reduces the set of allowable audio routes to only those appropriate for voice chat.

Not sure of the details, but anyhow it was found out that the SpeechRecognizer stops transcribing after a while of silence with the `.voiceChat` AVAudioSession mode.